# How to change html id into variable Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have this html line of code `<span id="mycount"></span>` which displays live data(number) from database so let's say it displays 5 from database. What I want to do is to use if statement like this`@if(5 > 0)`. So is it possible to change maybe the `id="mycount"` into a variable or any other way so that I can use if statement?

Html

```
<span id="mycount"></span>  //This displays 5
```

I want to have something like this

```
 @if(5 >0)
 //display data
 @else
 @endif
```

Javascript

```
function getCount() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '{{route('live.review')}}',
success: function(data) {
    $('#mycount').html(data);
   setTimeout(getCount, 1000);
}
});

}
getCount();
```

Comment: You're already making an AJAX request to the server to get the value, put the `if` condition in there.

Comment: how? @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer not to use the blade to handle this situation, as you are using ajax on the frontend to control this component of the DOM. an alternative that I would use in your case would be:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function getCount() {
 try {
   const data = axios.get('{{route('live.review')}}');
   const elCount = document.getElementById('#mycount');
   if (data > 0) {
     // const elText = document.createTextNode(data);
     // elCount.appendChild(elText);
     elCount.style.visibility = 'visible';
     elCount.innerHTML(data);
     return;
   }
   elCount.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 } catch (e) {
   window.console.error('Error! ', e.message);
 }
}

setTimeout(getCount, 1000);
```

Using Ajax

```
function getCount() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{ route("live.review") }}',
    success: (data) => {
      const elCount = jQuery('#myCount');
      if (data > 5) {
        elCount.html(data);
        elCount.show();
        return;
      }
      elCount.hide()
    },
    error: (error) => {
      window.console.error('Error! ', error.message)
    },
  });
}

setTimeout(getCount, 1000)
```

It is always good to also be sure of the returns of your request, so, for guarantee, every time you make a request, shoot a log with the result of the request just for guarantee `window.console.log(data)`(In development environment of course!)